# Multiple ways to communicate with Akka Actor from outside the system?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I was under the impression that the only way to communicate with an Akka Actor from *outside* the `ActorSystem` was via `Inbox`. However I just found [this snippet from Akka's own documentation](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-akka-java8#code/src/main/java/HelloAkka.java) which shows:

```
greeter.tell(new WhoToGreet("akka"), ActorRef.noSender());
inbox.send(greeter, new Greet());
```

So which is it? Is it in fact possible to directly `tell` an Actor from the outside world, or did Typesafe have a careless intern writing their documentation for them?!?

**If it is possible, then when should you do this, and when should you use `Inbox`?** For instance, is one method "fire-and-forget" asynchronous/non-blocking and the other synchronous/blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inbox` is part of the [relatively recent](http://letitcrash.com/post/32340419628/2-1-spotlight-shiny-new-actor-dsl) Actor DSL API that is "some nice sugar on top of the usual ways to create actors".  You can either use the standard way to create / communicate with actors or use the [Actor DSL](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/actordsl.html).  They are both async.  The Actor DSL is nice for creating one-off actors whose lifetime is one method.  The advantage of the DSL syntax is a bit more evident in Scala.

Comment: Thanks @sourcedelica (+1) - but which method is `Inbox`? Is `Inbox` the Actor DSL or is `Inbox` the "standard" way? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry - `Inbox` is part of the Actor DSL.  I've clarified and added a link to the Actor DSL page in the Scala reference manual.   It looks like there is not a corresponding page in the Java reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely send messages from outside an actor.  Akka will fill in a dummy sender.  You just won't be able to receive any replies (though you can use an `ask` for that).

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, but this doesn't answer my question. My question is when and where to use either approach...

Comment: Nobody can answer that without knowing your use case.

Comment: I highly doubt that! @Ryan, and I'm *sure* there is an appropriate time to use `greeter.tell(new WhoToGreet("akka"), ActorRef.noSender());` **instead of** `inbox.send(greeter, new Greet());`, and vice versa!